# firebase-admin python sending password reset email

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-admin

In Python I am trying to do 'send a password reset email', javascript reference (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sendPasswordResetEmail). So far (and only recently) it looks like 'generate password reset link' was added (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/releases). Does anyone know the next step in getting the email send? Do we send the email ourselves? If so, any suggestions? Is there a way to send the email in python directly?

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Might be late but for others to see:

```
email = 'user@example.com'
link = auth.generate_password_reset_link(email, action_code_settings)
# Construct password reset email from a template embedding the link, and send
# using a custom SMTP server.
send_custom_email(email, link)
```

More in here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#python_1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you (bojeil-google) on Github for providing the answer. Apparently, the way to do this is to make a POST request per https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-send-password-reset-email . There is no direct call to do this in the python SDK. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase-admin-sdk (python) is lack of methods to deal with user authentication. You can use [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase). It's a wrapper for the firebase API.